# Ubuntu 16.04 не перезагружается и не выключается

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, grub, dual-boot

На жестком диске дуал бут **Ubuntu 16.04** и **Windows 10**. Обе установлены в **UEFI** на **GPT**. Ubuntu не перезагружается и не выключается. Виснет на черном экране, приходится выключать кнопкой питания. Пробовал править **/etc/default/grub** редактируя строку **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** добавляя **acpi=force**, затем **acpi=off**, ничего не помогает. Через консоль также не выключается никакими командами (**reboot, shutdown, halt, poweroff**). C Windows все нормально в этом плане. Интересно то, что **archlinux** перезагружает и выключает норм. Но вот, **Manjaro**, который основан на **archlinux** также не перезагружает, как и пару других дистрибутивов на арче. Также дистрибутивы, которые основаны на дебиане последних версий не перезагружаются. А вот **Ubuntu 12.04** перезагружает. Версии выше 12.04 уже с проблемой. Несколько раз видел, что зависает на **Reached Target Shutdown**. Перезагружается только с **Ctrl+Sysrq REISUB**. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему?
Разбивка диска на разделы:

[image: Разделы жесткого диска]

Comment: попробуйте добавить «стандартные» «спасательные» параметры: `noapic nolapic noacpi irqpoll noapm nodma nomce`, и, если «поможет», убирайте по одному, пока не найдёте нужный.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо, но это не помогло

Comment: надеюсь, вы их добавляли прямо во время загрузки?

Comment: Мне помогло установкой обновлений в (настройки /о системе) просто туда обновлений много прилетает

Answer (score 4):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой после обновления,
прочитал случайно на оф форуме Ubuntы:
пересобрал инитрамфс:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

*Спасло*, кстати у Убунты давно такие глюки с выключением после обновы, не понятно что там выдумывают куча писак на с, с+, и с++, но эту проблему как будто ни кто не видит. Эта проблема давно у них.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте в БИОС нету ли пункта с ["xHCI Support"](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=267051.0). В AsusUSB Configuration XHCI Hand-Off (Enable) или  "change the USB 3 configuration in pre-OS state to be in enabled" Если у вас [HP](http://onthim.blogspot.com/2015/07/fix-ubuntu-shutdown-and-suspend-problem.html).